# Run Pytest Classes in Custom Order

Tags: python, function, class, pycharm, pytest

I am writing tests with pytest in pycharm. The tests are divided into various classes. 
I would like to specify certain **classes that have to run before other classes**. 
I have seen various questions on stackoverflow (such as [specifying pytest tests to run from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36456920/is-there-a-way-to-specify-which-pytest-tests-to-run-from-a-file) and [how to run a method before all other tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17801300/how-to-run-a-method-before-all-tests-in-all-classes)). 
These and various others questions wanted to choose specific **functions** to run in order. This can be done, I understand, using `fixtures` or with `pytest ordering`.
I don't care which functions from each class run first. All I care about is that the **classes** run in the order I specify. Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Approach

You can use the [`pytest_collection_modifyitems` hook](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_collection_modifyitems) to modify the order of collected tests (`items`) in place. This has the additional benefit of not having to install any third party libraries.

With some custom logic, this allows to sort by class.

#### Full example

Say we have three test classes:

1. `TestExtract`
2. `TestTransform`
3. `TestLoad`

Say also that, by default, the test order of execution would be alphabetical, i.e.:

`TestExtract` -> `TestLoad` -> `TestTransform`

which does not work for us due to test class interdependencies.

We can add `pytest_collection_modifyitems` to `conftest.py` as follows to enforce our desired execution order:

```py
# conftest.py
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(items):
    """Modifies test items in place to ensure test classes run in a given order."""
    CLASS_ORDER = ["TestExtract", "TestTransform", "TestLoad"]
    class_mapping = {item: item.cls.__name__ for item in items}

    sorted_items = items.copy()
    # Iteratively move tests of each class to the end of the test queue
    for class_ in CLASS_ORDER:
        sorted_items = [it for it in sorted_items if class_mapping[it] != class_] + [
            it for it in sorted_items if class_mapping[it] == class_
        ]
    items[:] = sorted_items
```

Some comments on the implementation details:

- Test classes can live in different modules
- `CLASS_ORDER` does not have to be exhaustive. You can reorder just those classes on which to want to enforce an order (but note: if reordered, any non-reordered class will execute before any reordered class)
- The test order within the classes is kept unchanged
- It is assumed that test classes have unique names
- `items` must be modified in place, hence the final `items[:]` assignment

Comment: This looks like just what I need! And, you even answered the follow up question I would've had, by saying that CLASS_ORDER does not have to be exhaustive. Thanks for this helpful answer!

Comment: I'm having a problem with this solution. Any time I try to run some of the tests, and don't include every single class that I'm sorting I get an error message. Any idea how to fix this besides for hiding the classes I'm not using from the list?

Comment: Answer edited to change the sorting algorithm to one that shouldn't have that issue (plus is more readable)

Comment: Thanks for the update. Works great! From what I understand, your new algorithm takes the class name, if it is in the list, and otherwise nothing. Is this correct?

Comment: Class by class according to the order defined in `CLASS_ORDER`, all tests belonging to a test class are moved to the end of the test queue (i.e. "execute last"). The order in `CLASS_ORDER` is enforced as a result.

Comment: Does this mean that the tests inside a class will run in a specific order, too?

Comment: Yes, as indicated in the answer *The test order within the classes is kept unchanged* (as we move tests one by one to the end of the test queue in the order we find them)

Answer (score 2):

@swimmer answer is great. I've modified it slightly to work with test organized into functions instead of classes.

```html
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(session, config, items):
    """Modifies test items in place to ensure test functions run in a given order"""
    function_order = ["test_one", "test_two"]
    # OR
    # function_order = ["test_one[1]", "test_two[2]"]  
    function_mapping = {item: item.name.split("[")[0] 
                        if "]" not in function_order[0] 
                        else item.name
                        for item in items}

    sorted_items = items.copy()
    for func_ in function_order:
        sorted_items = [it for it in sorted_items if function_mapping[it] != func_] + [it for it in sorted_items if function_mapping[it] == func_]
    items[:] = sorted_items
```