# pytest order test execution by grouping tests based on markers

Tags: pytest, pytest-markers, pytest-order

I am looking to execute tests cases in pytest using multiple markers (say `m1`, `m2`), such that all test cases marked with `m1` will run first, and then test cases marked `m2` will run after.
I am using the command: `pytest -s -m "m1 or m2"` to run pytest here.
Example:
`test_a` uses marker `m1`,
`test_b` uses marker `m2`,
`test_c` uses marker `m1`,
`test_d` uses marker `m2`.

If I execute `pytest -s -m "m1 or m2"`, the test execution order is: `test_a`->`test_b`->`test_c`->`test_d` because pytest executes them in an alphabetical order. But I want the execution to be `test_a`->`test_c`->`test_b`->`test_d` such that all tests marked `m1` are executed first, and then the tests marked `m2` are executed after.

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.m1
def test_a():
    pass

@pytest.mark.m2
def test_b():
    pass

@pytest.mark.m1
def test_c():
    pass

@pytest.mark.m2
def test_d():
    pass
```

Answer (score 4):

For completeness, there is now also an option to achieve this with `pytest-order`. The option [--order-marker-prefix](https://pytest-order.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#order-marker-prefix) now allows you to sort by your custom marker, while you are still able to filter by marker.

For your example, you can run the tests using

```
pytest --order-marker-prefix=m -s -m "m1 or m2"
```

to run the tests marked with "m1" before the tests marked with "m2". In this case the tests are handled the same way as if they had an additional order marker with the number as index, e.g. `@pytest.mark.m2` is handled like `@pytest.marker.order(2)`.

*Disclaimer*: I'm the maintainer of `pytest-order`. This question inspired me to add this feature.

Answer (score 1):

Getting a clue from @cdub's answer regarding `pytest_collection_modifyitems`, I could implement the following and got it to work. Reference to original implementaion from: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70738211/run-pytest-classes-in-custom-order#:~:text=You%20can%20use%20the%20pytest_collection_modifyitems,allows%20to%20sort%20by%20class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70738211/run-pytest-classes-in-custom-order#:%7E:text=You%20can%20use%20the%20pytest_collection_modifyitems,allows%20to%20sort%20by%20class).

```
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(items):
    """Modifies test items in place to ensure test functions run in a given order"""
    marker_order = ["m1", "m2"]
    marker_mapping = {}
    for item in items:
        if val := [x.name for x in item.own_markers if x.name in marker_order]:
            marker_mapping[item] = val[0]

    sorted_items = items.copy()
    for mark_ in marker_order:
        sorted_items = [it for it in sorted_items if it in marker_mapping and marker_mapping[it] != mark_] + \
                       [it for it in sorted_items if it in marker_mapping and marker_mapping[it] == mark_]

    items[:] = sorted_items
```

Answer (score 0):

`pytest -m "custom_marker"` runs all tests with that marker it does not change execution order.

I recommend looking into the [pytest-orde](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-order/)r plugin. This allows the use of a @pytest.marker.order(#) marker and can even be applied to the class level. So you could have all your m1 tests in one TestClass and all the m2 tests in another.

```py
import pytest

@pytest.marker.order(1)
class TestM1:

    def test_a(self):
        pass

    def test_c(self):
        pass

@pytest.marker.order(2)
class TestM2:

    def test_b(self):
        pass

    def test_d(self):
        pass
```

Alternatively you can try looking into the "pytest_collection_modifyitems" hook, but I am not very familiar with using it.